# jQuery unbind click handler with .off and then rebind with .on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to prevent a button from being clicked twice by accident by unbinding the click handler with .off like this...

```js
$(".button").click(function () {
    console.log("Button has been clicked and disabled");
  $( ".button" ).off();
});

$(".button2").click(function () {
    console.log("Button has been re-enabled");
  $( ".button" ).on();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">
    Click Me
</div>

<button class="button2">
    Re-enable click
</button>
```

I am struggling with rebinding it with .on, can anyone point me in the direction of an example or point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe [`one`](https://api.jquery.com/one/) is more what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, reading up on it now!

Comment: within .on mention event you want and its functionality..

Comment: The best solution is to put a flag on your function that indicates that the current function in progress, just like: function abc(started) { started = started || false; if (!started) setTimeout(function(){ return abc(true); },300 );}, use setTimeout to avoid double clicks, you can also add disabled attribute to get some visual feedback to the user.

Answer (score 2):

In your click function for button 2, re-enable the first button's click handling with : `$(".button").click(buttonOneClick);`
Here is an example:

```js
var buttonOneClick = function () {
    console.log("Button has been clicked and disabled");
  $( ".button" ).off();
};
$(".button").click(buttonOneClick);

$(".button2").click(function () {
    console.log("Button has been re-enabled");
    $(".button").click(buttonOneClick);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">
    Click Me
</div>

<button class="button2">
    Re-enable click
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Using `.one()`

using `.one()` there's no need to use `.off()` since the event is allowed only once. To re-enable the button you simply re-call the *enabling* function that does the `.one()` stuff:

```js
function buttonExec() {
  console.log("Button has been clicked and disabled");
}

function buttonEnable() {
  console.log("Button has been enabled");
  $(".button").one("click", buttonExec); // .one()
}

buttonEnable();                          // enable initially
$(".enable").on("click", buttonEnable);  // and on ".enable" click
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button">Click Me</button>
<button class="enable">Re-enable click</button>
```

## Using `.on()` and `.off()`

```js
function buttonExec() { 
  console.log("Button has been clicked and disabled");
  $(this).off("click");                  // .off() since we used .on()
}

function buttonEnable() {
  console.log("Button has been enabled");
  $(".button").on("click", buttonExec);  // .on()
}

buttonEnable();                          // enable initially
$(".enable").on("click", buttonEnable);  // and on ".enable" click
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button">Click Me</button>
<button class="enable">Re-enable click</button>
```

Comment: Can I use the first .one example with .this to make the function reusable?

Comment: @fightstarr20 well, you first need to know which `.enable` targets which `.button` - I don't know exactly what you're looking for, but if you use `$(this)` instead of  `$(".button")` the `this` will refer to the `".enable"` button.. which is not something you're after... Can you explain what's your HTML structure?

Comment: Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to apply it to https://jsfiddle.net/rsxqoru7/